# Image display on MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to display image on the cshtml file.
The spam filter prevents me from typing the HTML for image. However the source is set to

```
src= "@Html.Encode(Model.PictureLocation)"  alt="IMAGES"
```

In viewsource it shows as

```
src= "C:\Documents and Settings\xxx\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MVC\TIQC_ServerInterface\TIQC_ServerInterface\uploads\FileUpload12011_03_02_11_49_22.jpg"  alt="IMAGES"
```

The image is present in the location mentioned in the src path.

On execution, the page is not displaying the images. Let us know if anything wrong here?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You have specified an absolute path which doesn't exist on the client computer. Try like this:

```
<img src= "@Url.Content("~/uploads/FileUpload12011_03_02_11_49_22.jpg")" alt="IMAGES" />
```

or if your model variable contains "~/uploads/FileUpload12011_03_02_11_49_22.jpg" you could:

```
<img src= "@Url.Content(Model.PictureLocation)" alt="IMAGES" />
```

Comment: this would only work if the Files are located inside the Website Folder... How would you display files that are Locally Saved in the Server HardDrive?

Comment: @StevenHernandez, arbitrary hard drive files are not directly accessible by the client. Imagine what would happen if what you were asking was possible :-) If the files are not part of your website structure, you will have to explicitly write a server side handler (controller) to expose them and then have the client point to this custom handler.

Answer (score 2):

The path in the `src` attribute must be relative to the website root, not the absolute path on the server. So in your case that would probably be something like `"/uploads/FileUpload12011_03_02_11_49_22.jpg"`.