# How to display images in ASP.NET MVC view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In the `Index.cshtml` file, I'm trying to display the header image in the `wwwroot/images` folder, so I do

```
<img src="../../wwwroot/images/header.png" />
```

but the file won't show when I run the ASP.NET MVC project. I've spent a hours trying to mess around with the file paths and googling but the browser keeps giving me a "failed to load resource" error. What is the filepath?

[Screenshot of the project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHv0Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
  `<img src="~/wwwroot/images/header.png" style="height:200px;width:200px;"/>`
Refer these links for more options

[How to display an image from a path in asp.net MVC 4 and Razor view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986980/how-to-display-an-image-from-a-path-in-asp-net-mvc-4-and-razor-view)

[Image display on MVC view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248273/image-display-on-mvc-view)

Comment: still did not work, weird, it'll work if i use absolute image path from imgur but not from my local machine

Answer (score 0):

This will point the path to IIS folder path(C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express) if your image is not residing in this path then the image won't get displayed. You might consider using a relative path like below

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~\\Gallery\\" + item.Source)" />
```